# Radial stress of a cylinder that is longitudinally excited

Tags: pressure, symmetry, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, displacement

Consider a cylinder that is longitudinally excited on one of its ends and fixed on the other one as shown in the picture below.
[image: cylinder]
In the cylindrical coordinate system, the displacement vector $\bf u$ is defined as:
$${\bf u}=u_r(t,r,z) {\bf r_o}+u_z(t,r,z) {\bf z_o} \tag1$$
where $u_r$ is the radial displacement, $\bf r_o$ is the radial unit vector, $u_z$ is the longitudinal displacement and $\bf z_o$ is the longitudinal unit vector.

If a sinusoidal pressure is applied on the cylinder's free end, the cylinder will contract and expand in the radial direction due to the Poisson effect. So if there is radial expansion, then there is radial displacement.

I am assuming longitudinal and radial displacement exists at the radial boundary. But, does radial stress exist on the radial boundary? If it does, is it shear stress, or pressure stress?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary conditions of the problem read:

- prescribed displacement $\mathbf{u}(t,r,L) = \mathbf{0}$ on the constrained surface;
- prescribed null stress vector $\mathbf{t_n}(t,R,z) = \mathbf{\hat{n}}(t,R,z) \cdot \mathbb{T}(t,R,z) = \mathbf{0}$ on the free lateral surface, if you can neglect the influence of atmospheric pressure on the structure; here $\mathbb{T}$ is the stress tensor, the normal unit vector is equal to the unit vector pointing in radial direction $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, if we're assuming small strain, small displacement linear theory;
- on the surface at $z = 0$, the axial displacement is prescribed, while the other boundary conditions depend on the constraints on the surface:

  - if the points of the surface are free to move in radial direction, you need to prescribe zero component of the stress vector in the radial direction, namely

    $\mathbf{t_n}(t,r,0)  \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}} = \mathbf{\hat{n}}(t,R,z) \cdot \mathbb{T}(t,r,0)  \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}} = 0$;
  - if the points of the surface are not free to move in radial direction, you prescribe the radial displacement as well, prescribing the whole displacement vector

    $\mathbf{u}(t,r,0) = u_z^{b.c.}(t) \mathbf{\hat{z}}$.

**Useuful remark.** If you're using mathematical and numerical formulations of the problem relying on the **weak formulation**, like finite element method (**FEM**), you probably don't even need to find the explicit relation between the stress vector and tensor and your actual unknown, the displacement field $\mathbf{u}$, since surface contributions due to null surface stress are equal to the stress vector representing the external load, identically zero here.

Comment: This means that when we project the stress components at the point $(t, R, z)$ to the radial unit vector direction, we get zero stress. Projecting shear stress components to a unit vector that is normal to the shear stress direction always results in nullified projected components. So if I understand this correctly, this means that the shear stress at the point $(t, R, z)$ does not have to be necessarily zero, but radial pressure at that point must be zero. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: not exactly, the stress vector (unit force per unit surface) is $\mathbf{t_n} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{T}$ and it's a vector that could have 3 non-zero components, both in the direction perpendicular to the wall and in the directions parallel to the wall. If the lateral surface is free, i.e. there is no action on it (neglecting the atmospheric pressure), this vector is $\mathbf{t_n} = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Are you performing numerical simulations on the system? If so, what numerical method are you using? I ask, because if you're using FEM or other methods, you could ignore the explicit expression of this contribution in coordinates and set it to zero, so that we can avoid this computation. Anyway, no, this should be a vector condition $\mathbf{\hat{r}} T_{rr} + \mathbf{\hat{z}} T_{rz} + + \mathbf{\hat{\theta}} T_{r \theta}  = \mathbf{0}$. If you need to find the expression of the components of stress tensor, tlook in tables for cylindrical coordinates, instead of computing them from scratch

Comment: Great! If you need something else, try to ask again a new question. I could provide you some help, or at least I hope so.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I am going to try to analytically solve this problem. If I fail, I will try to solve it by using the finite difference method in Matlab. If I fail at that point also, I will make a 3D CAD model and try to solve it with the finite element method. :D